# Slicing a string in Python without brackets

Tags: python, string, slice

Let's say I have a string like `num = "12345"`; how do I print it as one character like `1` or `2` without using brackets (`print(num[0])`)?

Comment: Why would want to do this?

Comment: It's my homework but I really am stuck right now. Couldn't think of a way to do it without the brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brackets are probably the correct way to do this, why do not want you to use it?

Anyway, you can [unpack your string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) (only work with Python 3 as @DeepSpace precised), like this:

```
letter, *_ = num
print(letter)
# "1"
```

It works also for multiple variables anywhere:

```
letter_1, *_, letter_2 = num
print(letter_1, letter_2)
# "1", "5"
```

---

There is also [`operator.getitem(a, b)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.getitem), which behaves like the brackets but as a function:

```
from operator import getitem

letter = getitem(num, 0)
print(letter)
# "1"
```

---

Finally, as @EliKorvigo pointed it out, there is [`operator.itemgetter(item)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) which creates a function acting just like the brackets:

```
from operator import itemgetter

getter = itemgetter(3)
letter = getter(num)
print(letter)
# "4"
```

Comment: You can also add an `itemgetter` example.

Comment: @EliKorvigo Thank you, I added it.

Answer (score 0):

Another abuse of Python functions.

You could iterate over the string and only print values which are in a certain position.

```
num = '12345'

values = (0, 1)
for i, n in enumerate(num):
    if i in values:
        print(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using iterators:

```
chars = iter("12345")
print(next(chars))  # 1
print(next(chars))  # 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> num = '123456'
>>> ''.join(islice(num, 0, 1))    # same as num[0]
'1'
>>> n = 4
>>> ''.join(islice(num, n, n+1))  # same as num[4]
'5'
>>> n = 100
>>> ''.join(islice(num, n, n+1))  # _not_ the same as num[100]
''
>>> num[100]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Other ways to do it include looping over the input string the required number of times:

```
num = '123456'
n = 5
for i, c in enumerate(num):
    if i == n:
        print(c)
        break
# 6
```

Or popping items off a list copy of the string:

```
num = '123456'
l = list(num)
n = 5
for i in range(n):
    try:
        _ = l.pop(0)
    except IndexError:
        break
print(l.pop(0))
# 6
```

Or looping over an iterator version of the string:

```
num = '123456'
it = iter(num)
n = 5
for i in range(n):
    _ = next(it)
print(next(it))
```

And another way is to use a [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=deque#collections.deque):

```
from collections import deque

num = '123456'
d = deque(num)
n = 5
d.rotate(-n)
print d.popleft()
```

although you would want to length check it in case you rotated beyond the length of the string.